# Connection to database in NetBeans unsuccessful (error ora-00933)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans, database-connection

For school project I'm doing Music player using a simple database (for name, artist, length, album...) and I've done it 1/2 already but now when I'm trying to connect to school database **it gives me an error:**

`ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.`

I've checked my code thousand times but didnt find an error. **Here is the connection part (and sql command):**

```
try{ 
String name=display.getText();
String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@193.2.139.248:1521:ers";
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance();
Connection pb=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"username", "password");
Statement sta=pb.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=sta.executeQuery("select Song.Name, Artist.name from Song,Album,Artist where Song.Album_ID=Album.ID and Album.Artist_fk=Artist.ID and Song.name="+name);
       if(rs.next()){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, rs);
       }
       else{
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Song not found");
       }
       pb.close();
       }
       catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e.getMessage());
       }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: try this,                                                       executeQuery("select Song.Name, Artist.name from Song,Album,Artist where Song.Album_ID=Album.ID and Album.Artist_fk=Artist.ID and Song.name="+name+";");

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the pb.close into a finally like this, to ensure it is not closing the connection unexpectedly

```
finally
{
pb.close()
}
```

Also try running that query manually as it may be an issue with the query itself

Answer (score 0):

Variable `name` is not used properly in the `select` query.

Use `PreparedStatement` so that any special characters existing as part of the data are escaped safely.

**Change**:

```
Statement sta=pb.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=sta.executeQuery("select Song.Name, Artist.name from Song,Album,Artist 
                                where Song.Album_ID=Album.ID 
                                  and Album.Artist_fk=Artist.ID 
                                  and Song.name="+name);
```

**To**:

```
String sql = "select Song.Name, Artist.name from Song, Album, Artist
               where Song.Album_ID=Album.ID 
                 and Album.Artist_fk=Artist.ID 
                 and Song.name=?";
PreparedStatement pst = pb.prepareStatement( sql );
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your SQL query as :

```
ResultSet rs=sta.executeQuery("select Song.Name, Artist.name from Song,
Album,Artist where Song.Album_ID=Album.ID and Album.Artist_fk=Artist.ID 
and Song.name='" + name +'" ");
```

Since `name` is a String, you need to specify it within single quotes